# Build cuDNN framework with CPU fallback

Tags: c++, deep-learning, frameworks, cudnn

I am trying to implement some neural networks for training and inference using C++. It should work on GPU (if available, with cuDNN) and CPU (if GPU is not available).

All modern frameworks support this. However, I wonder how this is achieved. Are all functions, such as backprop etc., implemented twice - once with cuDNN, once with a CPU BLAS? How do they ensure that identical results are achieved?